# How to preserve backslashes when defining a command in vim?

Tags: search, vim, escaping

I'm trying to define a makeshift search function, based on a blog entry, to use with `ag`. Currently, the code is:

```
set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolour\ --vimgrep
command! -nargs=+ -complete=file -bar MyAg silent! grep! <args>|cwindow|redraw!
nnoremap <leader>a :MyAg<SPACE>
```

This works fine until I need to search for double quotes, where escaping is required. Consider the following example:

```
:set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolour\ --vimgrep
:grep --php \".*jQuery.*\"
```

This code works fine. In contrast, given the above `MyAg` vim command definition, consider the following search:

```
:MyAg  --php \".*jQuery.*\"
```

results in the following invocation:

```
:ag --vimgrep --php ".*jQuery.*"
```

The backslashes are gone, and with them the point of the search.

How can I define `MyAg` above so as to preserve the escaping? (or, rather, to prevent vim from processing the backslashes on its own and pass them through, untouched.)

`<q-args>` adds a pair of single quotes to the whole expression, like so:

```
:ag '--vimgrep --php ".*jQuery.*"'
    ^                            ^
```

Which apparently is an invalid command.

PS I'm interested in making this work, and am aware of `vim-ack` and `vim-ag`.

Comment: Can't you just double escape them? `\\".*jQuery.*\\"`

Comment: @lukas-reineke Indeed, that's a solution. A logical continuation would be to define a function to unconditionally double backslashes and then pass the preprocessed string as the argument to `command`. Still, I'm curious if there is a built-in operation in `vim` for such auto-escaping?

Comment: There is `:h escape()`. You might be able to use that in the command to escape the string again for grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swallowing of the backslashes seems to be caused by the `-bar` command modifier. Compare:

```
:command! -nargs=+ -complete=file -bar MyAg echo '<args>'
:MyAg \"foo\"
"foo"
```

with:

```
:command! -nargs=+ -complete=file MyAg echo '<args>'
:MyAg \"foo\"
\"foo\"
```

This cannot be worked around with `<q-args>`, neither.
I couldn't find a definite statement in the `:help`, but I guess this has to do with the fact that with `-bar`, Vim has to parse the remainder for a `|` command separator, and that means that escaping comes into play.

It's laudable that you've attempted to support command chaining, but in this case, better drop it. It would cause problems with regular expression branches (in `grep`: `foo\|bar`), anyway.

Comment: To be honest with you, I found the command in a blog post, and the command chaining part was already there. Anyway, thank you!